# Road trip US - correct IDs missing

Tags: usa, international-travel, eu-citizens, identity-cards, officials

This is (fortunately) a purely hypothetical question.

If I, as Citizen in the European Union, make a road trip in the USA, get in a police traffic control an only have my local IDs with me (not my international passport or the international drivers license), what consequences do I have to fear?

Comment: What do you mean by "local IDs"? Unlike many places, in the USA you're required to carry your driving license while actually driving.

Comment: In this case I would have my German personal ID and my German driving licence with me, but not my international passport and international drivers licence  (afaik the local drivers license is not valid in other countries outside the EU)

Comment: You are aware that the internatinonal driving licence is actually not a licence in itself, but merely a translation of your existing licence? You're generally expected to present both of them to foreign police (at least, outside the EU).

Comment: By ‘with me’ do you mean at that particular moment, or that you don’t possess an IDL and/or a valid passport?

Comment: In the US drivers licenses are considered a form of ID.

Comment: Traveller assume I have it "in another jacket" but I'm in possession of the needed documents in general

Comment: @MichaelHampton driver licensing laws vary from state to state, as I suppose you probably know.  In some states it is not actually required to have the license in your personal possession while driving.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk a driver's license is an identification document in any event, because it needs to identify the person whom it authorizes to drive.  Whether it is sufficient identification for any given purpose varies.  But there certainly are countries in the EU where a driver's license may be used as identification in some contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a police traffic control, as in all countries, you must have the documentation required by the local law.

In most cases this will be a valid **driver's licence** and papers for the car.

For a foreign lincense some countries (and some US States) require a IDP (international drivers permit/license).

Depending on the situation, a police officer could also demand documentation of citizenship and/or legal status through an National ID or passport.

In the US the last is less likely, unless you run into a control done by the **United States Border Patrol**, where - as a visitor - a passport may be required.

What may happen to you if you cannot supply the needed documentation will depend on the laws of the local authorities, which can differ greatly.

Assume: **no joy will fall upon you**.

Comment: Is there a legal requirement to carry a passport in the USA? In the UK, you don’t need to carry any ID at all.

Comment: @greatone It varies by state whether you have to carry ID at all times. But in every state you have to carry your driver license while driving. It's a good idea to carry your passport near the border as there are occasionally random Border Patrol checks internally.

Comment: @greatone Many motels ask for one when checking in. I gave my German ID to my US- Citizen friend who mostly paid upfront. He said they barely looked at it. But in one case it was rejected and a passport was asked for with no reason given why. I assume if they don't what it is, they ask for something else.

Comment: To keep this in proportion, I've lived as an alien in the US within 100 miles of the Mexico border since 1975. I have had to show the Border Patrol documentation while driving in the area exactly once.

Comment: @greatone there is a federal requirement for most aliens to carry any "registration receipt" which they have been issued. Federal officers sometimes overstate the requirement or misrepresent it entirely, and the regulation concerning passport is stamps is vague, but for a tourist the requirement should be satisfied by carrying either an I-94 (printed from the website) or the passport with admission stamp. Enforcement is virtually nonexistent unless one encounters a US Border Patrol officer (not CBP). They mostly operate within 100 miles of Mexico and Canada, also in Florida.

Comment: @MarkJohnson indeed.  Accepting a national ID would be in the discretion of the officer, but it certainly does not satisfy any legal requirement to show a passport.  Also, whether a police officer would inquire about nationality or immigration status depends more on the department than on any other circumstance.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan but there are certain fixed checkpoints where one is virtually guaranteed to encounter USBP, are there not?

Comment: @phoog that statement was only in contex of a motel, where state by state it seems to be different requirements.

Comment: @phoog My experience includes driving through those checkpoints many times. Usually they just wave me through. I have been stopped and questioned only twice. One time I was asked for documentation. The other time they asked me to state my nationality. I said "British citizen, US permanent resident", and they waved me on.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes, but most visitors will not be speaking with a local accent and driving a local car. So for those having the documents required by law is advised.

Comment: @MarkJohnson A rental car might be more suspicious. I do always have my green card in my possession, as legally required.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan from what I know of these checkpoints it seems likely that US permanent residents and even naturalized citizens of certain racial appearance would be likely to have rather different experiences from yours.  Tourists in these areas should probably take that into account and being their I-94. The thing that irritates me about these checkpoints is that USBP misrepresents 8 USC 1304 as a requirement to carry proof of immigration status, which it is not, and that it applies to all foreigners, which it does not.

Comment: @phoog I agree. At one time I had a colleague who was both Latino and a very smart programmer. As a single young man with a good job, he had a nice car. He got stopped almost every time. Apparently, the border patrol thought that the only way a young Latino could afford that sort of car was by smuggling, drugs or people. My white female face and more modest car got me through almost every time.

Comment: @phoog I live within 100 miles of the Canadian border, and for several years lived in a county that bordered on Canada. I have never heard of a fixed border patrol checkpoint, that is, a checkpoint that is always manned. Instead, such checkpoints are set up from time to time at random spots on highways. I personally have never encountered any of these checkpoints.

Comment: @GerardAshton the permanent ones are all near Mexico.  See for example https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/along-us-borders/border-patrol-sectors/rio-grande-valley-sector-texas/falfurrias-station.

Comment: The checkpoints I know are not necessarily manned all the time, but they are fixed installations at locations that are difficult to bypass.

Comment: One of the most notable checkpoints is on I-10 east of El Paso around Sierra Blanca (31°11′29.84″N 105°25′46.83″W). If you are driving coast to coast on I-10, you will hit the checkpoint, and it is open most of the time. If you hit it, you WILL be asked if you are a citizen, and if you honestly answer "no" you will be expected to have some sort of documentation. If you didn't have it, they would likely detain you until they have positive identification, which would not be pleasant.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, police are state or local officials, not national officials (with rare exceptions, such as on military bases). Their main concern is enforcing state laws and local ordinances, not enforcing immigration rules. I don't think I've ever read the phrase "police traffic control" before. Police do occasionally set up checkpoints where they stop each car and speak briefly to the driver. During these stops their main concern is to see if the driver appears to be under the influence of alcohol or drugs.

If an officer requests a driver to show a driver license, in some states the officer will accept a foreign license by itself; in other states the officer may require it be presented together with an international driving permit.